# Is font configuration available in jhs(J HTTP Server)?

Tags: fonts, j

I use J in my chromebook with the help of crouton.
Because I couldn't set the gtk environment for J gtk in my chromebook, 
I usually launch jhs in my chrome browser. 
Overall I am so satisfied with jhs ide, 
but only one tiny problem itches me, 
I can't find font configuration file or menu in jhs.
I'd like to display Korean characters in fixed width
so that tidy arrangement with box-draw characters such as '+++++++++|-'.
I've tried font-setting of chrome browser in fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: `configdefault_jhs_`

Try:

```
PC_FONTFIXED_jhs_=:'"sans-serif"' NB. or the font you really want
```

press F5 to refresh ijx window to see change